# Co-editing PowerPoint in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powerpoint, co-authoring

Is it possible to configure SharePoint 2010 to allow co-authoring / co-editing of PowerPoint decks simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, co-authoring is available inSP 2010. You need to make sure following things:

1. All users must have at least edit permission on the library
2. Versioning should enable on the document library in order to track the changes
3. Require Check Out should not be enabled in document libraries. If it is enabled then co authoring will be disabled.

Read more here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934618(v=office.14).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934620(v=office.14).aspx